# on_touch_down shouldnt update counter when on_touch_move - kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am running on_touch_down and on_touch_move and in need to update the counter whenever a move is done or touch down is done . 
However I dont want to update touch down when we just did touch move .but by default even if its just a touch_move it still adds 1 to touch down , i think that is because on move event detects first touch down , but is there any way to fix this :

Below is a sample code .

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class JB(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(JB, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.touch_move_count = 0
        self.touch_down_count = 0
        self.touch_move_Label = Label()
        self.touch_down_Label = Label()
        self.update_count()
        self.add_widget(self.touch_down_Label)
        self.add_widget(self.touch_move_Label)

    def update_count(self):
        self.touch_down_Label.text = "Touch Down Count : %s"%str(self.touch_down_count)
        self.touch_move_Label.text = "Touch Move Count : %s"%str(self.touch_move_count)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.touch_down_count += 1
        print "down", self.touch_down_count
        self.update_count()

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.touch_move_count += 1
        print "moved", self.touch_move_count
        self.update_count()


class MyJBApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.parent = JB()
        return self.parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyJBApp().run()
```

Comment: I just tested your code, and it does exactly what it should for me, which apparently isn't the same as what you get. That is, pressing the mouse button updates the first counter but not the second, then moving the mouse updates the second counter but not the first. Could you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: you are getting the correct output but this is not what i want . I want that if i am pressing and then moving in same press then 1st counter i.e. touch down counter should be still 0,however the other counter i.e. touch move should start increasing . if i dont move but only press at a particular position , touch down should be 1 , touch move should be 0 .

Answer (score 1):

You still touched down on the button before moving - a touch down event will always be sent, because at that moment the application doesn't know if you're going to move or not. If you want to know if a touch happened without a move, you could utilize touch up as well:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    self.is_touch_down = True

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if self.is_touch_down:
        self.touch_down_count += 1
        print "down", self.touch_down_count
        self.update_count()
    self.is_touch_down = False

def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    self.is_touch_down = False
    self.touch_move_count += 1
    print "moved", self.touch_move_count
    self.update_count()
```

You could also do something more elaborate by saving the received touch in `on_touch_down`, then checking in `on_touch_up` that the position is within some tolerance (like 4px or something).